# transfer exe file from Ubuntu oracle virtual box to host machine (windows 7 )

Tags: windows, virtualbox, executable, transfer

I want to transfer an executable file from Ubuntu to Windows. I've tried via shared folder of the VM I have Ubuntu installed in. It works, but when I open the executable file in Windows, the file is not defined (not exe file).

The executable file (`sphinx3_align`) is part of the package *sphinx3 tool*. After running *sphinx3 tool*, I copied `sphinx3_align` from `/usr/local/bin` to the shared folder, but when I  open it in Windows, it tells me that the file is not defined.

Output of `file sphinx3_align`:

```
sphinx3_align: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
  dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
  BuildID[sha1]=d4584be6f1adc0b0a8471cd8e774a79c53b1f7f3, not stripped
```

How do I transfer this file to a Windows system ?

Comment: Is the executable file a `.exe` file on the Ubuntu VM? By default Ubuntu doesn't use `.exe` files and runs either compiled code (without an extension) or interprets various languages (eg. Python, Perl, Lisp - these all have their own extensions). If the file isn't a `.exe` on Ubuntu (it would have to be running under WINE) then it won't run under Windows. However, if it is an SH script (extension `.sh`) we may be able to convert to a `.bat` (BAT script, Windows equivalent).

Comment: If you've downloaded the executable from the internet; you may be able to grab the same version for Windows from the publisher. Edit your question to include the name of the executable and where you got it from.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include both the full name (with extension, if existing) of the file as well as the terminal output of `file /INSERT/FULL/PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE/HERE`. That way we can see whether it's a valid Windows .exe program or a Linux executable/script.

Comment: the exe file (sphinx3_align ) is part of package sphinx3 tool , after run sphinx3 tool copy sphinx3_align from usr/local/bin to shared folder , but when i  open in windows the file not defind .

Comment: @ByteCommander check to edit question

Answer (score 0):

You can not run this file on a Windows system! Never. No chance.

As you can see in the output of `file`, it says `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, [...] for GNU/Linux 2.6.24`. ELF is the format for compiled binary executables Linux uses, and it even tells you that this program is written for a Linux kernel 2.6.24 (which seems pretty old, as well as the CPU architecture it tells... - but that's not important).

Windows in contrast uses the PE format for compiled binary executables (known as `*.exe` files). And as well as you may not natively run Windows `.exe` files on Ubuntu/Linux, you may also not run any Ubuntu executable binaries on Windows.

There is `wine` to run Windows applications on Linux (which does not work with all software anyway, but only some programs), but I have not heard of an emulator to execute Linux programs on Windows yet. You will have to stay with that program inside your Ubuntu VM or search the internet for a Windows-compatible download.

Comment: Okay , but i don't run in windows , just i need copy of executable file to put in another linux machine . clear ???

Comment: Well, you may copy how often and wherever you want - you just may *not execute it on Windows!* Windows won't recognize it as binary executable, because of the incompatible formats. Just that Windows does say it's no exe file (which it definitely really isn't, it's an ELF file!) does not mean it got broken during the copying process.

Comment: okay , then what solution to transfer these file ?? Is impossible ??

Comment: You may transfer that file however and wherever you want! This is possible. However, I don't know if it will work if you just copy a single file over to another system. If you installed it from a package, you should better copy that whole package instead of just a single binary. It is not important _how_ you transfer it, but _what_ you transfer and _what_ you are going to do with it _where_...

Comment: @SafiaHammad: This is 100% correct so don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**
The above is also why iPhone games don't run on Android or on Linux or on Windows...à